# Plot borders larger than set extent (Terra in R)

Tags: r, maps, terra, plotting

I am trying to plot what I think is a very simple map. I have three inputs, map of Canada, map of USA, and a shapefile with rivers. I have set my extent, and when plotting the map I can see a cutoff line (not a border) at that longitude but then the map and axis extends beyond that point (latitude is plotting within the extent I set).

Very basically (without the river shape file),

```
Canada_adm <- gadm(country = "Canada", level =1, path = "/outputs")
USA_adm <- gadm(country = "United States", level = 1, path = "/outputs")

TOB_ext <- ext(-68, -65.7, 44.5, 47.5) 

plot(Canada_adm, ext = TOB_ext)
plot(USA_adm, add = TRUE)
```

The resulting plot (in my plot window) shows the x-axis spanning ~-69.5 to ~-64, when I've tried to set it to -68 to -65.7. How do I set the overall plot to match the extent that I want, rather than just the maps (Canada/USA) being trimmed to the extent?